# ORACLE Query occurrence for an element

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I'll try to explain with a generic example:

I have a table in MySQL with two columns: "Product" and "Client". For each product a client buy, a register is generated in this table.

Now I took 2 products, Stove and Refrigerator, and I want to find the client that bought both products and just them.

[image: table example]

In this case, the expected result would be **Marley**, and why not Maria too? Because beyond the stove and refrigerator she also bought a chair.

How could be a <strike>MySQL</strike> ORACLE select query to give me that result?

edit: the question was wrong, it's Oracle and not MySQL, thanks Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation.  Assuming there are no duplicates in the table:

```
select client
from t
group by client
having sum( product in ('Stove', 'Refrigerator') ) = 2 and
       count(*) = 2;
```

If there are duplicates, the logic is:

```
select client
from t
group by client
having count(distinct case when product in ('Stove', 'Refrigerator') then product end ) = 2 and
       count(distinct product) = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks, it was what I was looking for
Just another question, when I use it like the first case I get the message:
"ORA-00907: right parenthesis not found"

Do you have any idea why? I just could found that the problem is here: sum(product in ('Stove', 'Refrigerator'))

Comment: @hyfronx . . . The question is tagged MySQL, so the answer is for MySQL.  The equivalent logic in Oracle would be:  `having sum(case when product in ('Stove', 'Refrigerator')  then 1 else 0 end) = 2`.

Answer (score 1):

Concept Used:

- Filter record for `Stove` and `Refrigerator`.
- Group records by `Client`
- Each `Client` should have exactly two distinct records, if yes then it should be in result set.

```
SELECT Client
FROM table
WHERE Product IN ('Stove', 'Refrigerator')
GROUP BY Client
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Product) = 2
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. Skip those extra brackets and simply write `COUNT(DISTINCT Product)` to make code clearer!

Comment: Your WHERE has to pass all non-wanted items. Use HAVING to validate none of them exists.